# Semantic UI Grid with more than 16 Columns?

Tags: css, grid-layout, semantic-ui

I am currently starting a new project based on Semantic UI.

In [Semantic UI's grid documentation](http://semantic-ui.com/collections/grid.html) there is described that the default number of columns is 16, but it can be adjusted using theming variables:

> The default column count, and other arbitrary
>   features of grids can be changed by adjusting
>   Semantic UI's underlying theming variables.

I am considering whether using a number of columns based on 3 would be a better choice?
But since 12 (as in Bootstrap) appears a bit too narrow for me, I am thinking whether 24 columns (2*2*2*3) would be good.

Has anyone of you ever thought about using **more** than 16 columns?

Comment: Yup, I've thought about using 24 columns in the past -- not supporting thirds in the layout is a serious weakness of a 16 column grid.  Haven't tried altering the theme variables, but would definitely +1 this change if it were a pull request.